# JNA - Unable to get a call from native function to a callback function

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I am using JNA to call functions of a dll file.

One of the functions requires a pointer to a callback function

```
// Dll function
void MyFunction (*CallBackFnName);
```

Below is the JNA proxy interface in java

```
import com.sun.jna.Callback;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public interface Dll extends Library {

interface CallBackFnName extends Callback {
    void callback(Pointer dataBuffer, int dataLen);
}


public void MyFunction(Dll.CallBackFnName fn);
public int StartReading(short arg1, short arg2);

}
```

According to the API of the dll, after passing the pointer to a **callback function** to the function **MyFunction(*CallBackFnName)**, whenever you call **StartReading()** function it will send data to the callback function.

When I am trying to do that, It is not calling my callback function. It is not throwing any exception also.

Below is the code from which I am calling functions:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class Start {

private static Dll dll = (Dll) Native.loadLibrary("MyDll", Dll.class);
private static Dll.CallBackFnName fn = new Dll.CallBackFnName() {
    @Override
    public void callback(Pointer dataBuffer, int dataLen) {
        System.err.println("Callback function is called successfully");
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    dll.MyFunction(fn); //passed the pointer to the callback function
    short arg1 = 0;
    short arg2 = 0;
    dll.StartReading(arg1, arg2));
    Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
}
}
```

After running the above code, I am getting the following on the console:

```
DeviceAttach: received and accepted attach for vendor id 0x3eb, product id 0x2ffd,         interface 0, device handle 0x037825E8
Main Menu (active Dev/Prod/Interface/Alt. Setting: 0x3eb/0x2ffd/0/0)

Read FailReadWritePipesMenu: WDU_Transfer(control receive) failed: error 0x2000000e ("
Read Fail")

Read FailReadWritePipesMenu: WDU_Transfer(control receive) failed: error 0x2000000e ("
Read Fail")

Read FailReadWritePipesMenu: WDU_Transfer(control receive) failed: error 0x2000000e ("
Read Fail")
Transferred 0 bytes
0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need the answer , but to anyone else who has this problem,
I had this problem before.I had to create an anonymous class as such (using the above example),

```
dll.myfunc(new Dll.CallBackFnName() {
@Override
public void callback(Pointer dataBuffer, int dataLen) {
    System.err.println("Callback function is called successfully");
} } );
```

This worked for me . although i can't explain why.